# Can CRON job pass the updated value of existing environment variable to a shell script?

Tags: bash, docker, cron, alpine-linux

This is my cron script : `* * * * * /script.sh >> /var/log/script.log`

My script.sh file

'''

```
#!/bin/sh

env
echo $DISABLE_CACHE

if [ "$DISABLE_CACHE" = "true" ]
then
    echo " RELOADING NGINX "
else
    echo "Routine cron job"
fi
```

'''

So when the cron job starts, DISABLE_CACHE variable value was set to true.
Its a string variable not Boolean.

But now when I purposely change the DISABLE_CACHE variable value to false due to some requirement, I was able to see the changes outside cron script by firing "env" command from my terminal.

But Inside cron job, it still prints old env value in my /var/log/script.log file.

Any idea how can my cron job get the updated value of existing env variable?

FYI:

This whole setup I was trying inside alpine docker container

Comment: Each process has its own environment. Changing an environment variable in one process will have no effect on other processes (like the cron job). (Exception: forked subprocesses get a copy of the parent process's environment. But the cron job is forked from crond, not your shell process.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So there is no workaround for this kind of situation?

Comment: You should write something into some file, perhaps in /var/run/...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a file. I changed disable_cache to lowercase.

```
#!/bin/bash
env
nginx_cache=/etc/nginx_cache
test -f "${nginx_cache}" && disable_cache=$(<"${nginx_cache}")
echo "$disable_cache"

if [ "$disable_cache" = "true" ]
then
    echo " RELOADING NGINX "
else
    echo "Routine cron job"
fi
```

Now you can change the setting outside the script with `echo "true" > /etc/nginx_cache` .